# IPTables Forwarding Port 8080 to 80

Tags: iptables, httpd, 301-redirect

My hardware firewall has port 8080 open

My goal is to have my server receive the requests over 8080 and via iptables route the request to be handled by httpd.

This seems simple (in my head), but I am missing something.

Here are my IPTable Rules:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6:782]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1:732]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:732]
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination :80
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [87:12324]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

When I attempt to request a site I am getting a 301 redirect and not the site (test via curl):

```
* About to connect() to server.domain.com port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying <ip addy>... connected
* Connected to server.domain.com (<ip addy>) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: server.domain.com:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Wed, 08 Nov 2017 19:07:32 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
< Set-Cookie: cf7msm_check=1; path=/
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=0lblsu0t9of4id2nraei0v7rb0; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-Pingback: http://server.domain.com/wp/xmlrpc.php
< Location: http://server.domain.com/
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Closing connection #0
```

HTTPD is setup to listen on 80.

The requests are getting to HTTPd, but for a reason I have not yet figured out, the requests are not getting the expected responses.

If I change everything to use straight port 80 everything works fine.

Comment: This must be because the http client (here, curl) gives the non-standard 8080 port in the Host field. Can’t you just configure yout httpd to (also) listen on port 8080?

Comment: I just changed the httpd conf to allow 80 and 8080.  Still the same 301 Moved Permanently.  I am beginning to think this is more of a httpd issue than a iptables issue.  Originally I thought I was fubar'ing the IPtables config.

Answer (score 2):

Your 301 redirect is coming from WordPress. You need to put the correct port number in Settings > General if you intend to run WordPress on a nonstandard port.

Comment: Thanks for this, but should not my redirect using IPTables allow WP to see the request as coming over port 80?  Or, at least that was my goal, was to not change the WP configuration and masquerade my requests to 8080 as coming in via 80.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. As far as any web app knows, the request came in on port 8080. If you really want it to run on port 80, why are you bothering with this redirect at all?

Comment: Sorry, but is that not exactly what port-forwarding is?  redirecting an external port to a different internal port?  I can tell you that, via tcpdump, the server is seeing the requests on port 80.  Thus, I am confused as to how WP is still seeing it via 8080.  The only reason for this setup was that our port 80 is already in use @ hardware firewall; thus, I wanted to use a different external port.  Add to that, I was simply copying a WP site to a temp instance and I did not want to go through any effort of WP cfg change.

Comment: Because WordPress knows nothing about TCP. It only sees your HTTP request, which references port 8080.